# Adding a secret value to an EcsJobDefinition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk, aws-batch

I am trying to add a secret value to my ECS Job definition,

```
        secret_id = f"mysecretid"
        secret = secretsmanager.Secret.from_secret_name_v2(
            self,
            secret_id,
            secret_name=secret_id,
        )

        # Mongo DB URI
        mongodb_uri = ecs.Secret.from_secrets_manager(secret, "MONGODB_URI")

        job_definition = batch.EcsJobDefinition(self, f"{stage}{NAME}JobDefinition",
            container=batch.EcsEc2ContainerDefinition(self, "Container",
                image=image,
                memory=Size.mebibytes(4096),
                cpu=2,
                secrets={"MONGO_DB_URI": mongodb_uri},
                command=["npm run crawl"],
            )
        )
```

I am running into the error,

```
RuntimeError: Passed to parameter props of new aws-cdk-lib.aws_batch.EcsEc2ContainerDefinition: Unable to deserialize value as aws-cdk-lib.aws_batch.EcsEc2ContainerDefinitionProps
├──  Failing value is an object
│      { '$jsii.struct': [Object] }
╰──  Failure reason(s):
    ╰─ Key 'secrets': Unable to deserialize value as map<aws-cdk-lib.aws_batch.Secret> | undefined
        ├──  Failing value is an object
        │      { '$jsii.map': [Object] }
        ╰──  Failure reason(s):
            ╰─ Key 'MONGO_DB_URI': Unable to deserialize value as aws-cdk-lib.aws_batch.Secret
                ├──  Failing value is an object
                │      { '$jsii.byref': 'aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs.Secret@10003' }
                ╰──  Failure reason(s):
                    ╰─ Object of type 'aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs.Secret' is not convertible to aws-cdk-lib.aws_batch.Secret
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is fairly clear:

```
Object of type 'aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs.Secret' is not convertible to aws-cdk-lib.aws_batch.Secret
```

Since you are creating a Batch Job, instead of an ECS Task, it is expecting a Batch secret instead of an ECS secret. You need to use the [batch version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_batch/Secret.html) of the secret reference.

Change your code to this:

```
# Mongo DB URI
mongodb_uri = batch.Secret.from_secrets_manager(secret, "MONGODB_URI")
```